# HttpClient statusCodes

Tags: java, httpclient

Im using HttpCLient to autoLogin a website. I an getting statusCode as '200'. API says SC 200 - OK. what does that mean? Login is established?
When I see the list of statusCodes there is SC Accepted - 202. What is the difference between Accepted and OK.
If login is established what status code should I get? Please help.

pesudo code if this helps to answer:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

public class HttpTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws HttpException, IOException {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // make the initial get to get the SESSION cookie
    GetMethod get = new GetMethod(
    "http://www.yahoo.com/");
    client.executeMethod(get);
    get.releaseConnection();

    // authorize
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(
    "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?");
    NameValuePair[] data = {
    new NameValuePair("login", "aaa@yahoo.com"),
    new NameValuePair("passwd", "bbb")
    };
    post.setRequestBody(data);
    client.executeMethod(post);
    post.releaseConnection();

    //resubmit the original request
    client.executeMethod(get);
    String response = get.getResponseBodyAsString();
    get.releaseConnection();
    System.out.println("Status Code :::"+get.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println(response);    
    }
}
```

This is the form based authentication i hvae been trying. I am getting the same issue here...200-ok for improper credentials. Im using a common website like yahoo to login. Any advice?

Comment: Depends on the implementation, you should check their API documentation for what they mean by 200 and 210.

Comment: Well, try the other case!  Attempt a login with incorrect credentials and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's HttpClient status codes are the same as the status codes defined in RFC1945 (HTTP 1.0), RFC2616 (HTTP 2.0) and RFC2618 (WebDAV).

These specific codes mean:

**200 OK**

The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request, for example:

GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the response;

HEAD the entity-header fields corresponding to the requested resource are sent in the response without any message-body;

POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;

TRACE an entity containing the request message as received by the end server.

**202 Accepted**

The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.

The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed. The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled.

For definitions of the other common HTTP status codes, see [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Thanks much. To double check I changed the password and even now, i see SC 200. I dont understand now.

Comment: The best we can do without more information is to enumerate what the HTTP responses mean. Without knowing the specifics of the system you're logging into, we can't really say what sort of response you should expect. For most systems I'm tempted to say 200 OK should be sent whether you succeed or fail, but that the body of the response should contain the success or failure status (as opposed to the header where the statusCode lives)

Comment: To be 100% clear, statusCode 200 simply means that the HTTP server has received your packets without error and is responding to them. statusCode probably isn't the appropriate place to look in order to determine success/failure of the login for most systems.

Comment: I have edited my Q and added the pesudo code. I checked with some random sites and everything gives SC 200 with improper crendentials. Not sure what is wrong. How can i debug. How can i get the response in detail?

Comment: Unless you're attempting HTTP authentication you will almost always get a 200 OK response. Try using getResponseBody(), which will contain the full HTML response of the web server. Chances are you'll see some kind of "login failed" or "login succeeded" message in the response body which you can parse. If you **are** attempting HTTP authentication, try to access a restricted resource and check for a statusCode of 403.

Comment: getResponseBody() is from httpMethos right. Im not suing HttoMethod here. If possible can you gv me an example?

Comment: Try the [httpEntity documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) - there's a good example of httpEntity.getContent right at the beginning

Comment: Im using this getContent in my example above and use buffered reader. The content that gets displayed is the HTML of the login page. It doesnt tell me the login status.

Comment: `httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials` is HTTP authentication, which is completely different from form-based authentication. If you're seeing an HTML login form then they're probably not using HTTP authentication, you'll need to send an appropriate POST to the server to emulate the form's function.

Comment: I have updated the code to use form based authentication. Still I face the same issue. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

[200 means the request was successful](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and the response is based on that successful request.  202 would mean that the request was successful and has been queued for processing on the server, so the response isn't based on successful completion of the request because it hasn't necessarily completed yet.

Think of it like a short conversational exchange...

**200:**

> **Client:** Here is my request
> **Server:** Thanks!  I've processed your request.  Here's the response you were looking for.

vs.

**202:**

> **Client:** Here is my request
> **Server:** Thanks!  I'm not done processing it yet, but I'm just letting you know that I've received it and it's under way.

I can't imagine a login taking a long time, so I'd expect a successful login to always return a 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

`202 Accepted` means, your request is getting processed by the receiver (something like I got your application will look into it).

`200 OK` means, Your application was processed and granted what you requested (whether it could be login (or) request for another resource).

Answer (score 0):

Review this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

But as milan stated you should review the API and make sure the API is using those error codes  the same way the standard says to use them.

For example, you could try a login get a 200, but the payload returned has a login failure message.

A better behaved implementation would return a 200 for a good login and a 401 or 403 on a bad login.

Answer (score 0):

We were using following code for status code outputs. Note that classes first is a pojo objects from server response:

```
public void doFirst(int i) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("url" + i);
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(request);
if(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
    System.err.println(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
Gson gson = new Gson();
first ress = gson.fromJson(json, first.class);
System.out.println("Incoming data: " + ress.getNumber());

/////some action///////
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url" + i);
firstSol sol= new firstSol();
sol.setNumber(k);
System.out.println("Data to send : " + gson.toJson(sol) );
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(gson.toJson(sol)));
client.execute(post);
HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(request);
if(response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
System.err.println(response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
}
```

you might have a look at following maven dependencies for this to work:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the effort to describe your code, it helps the asker and the community.